# Counter array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I  am trying to make two arrays. the unique array can get the elements (no repeats) from the text array, and the counter one can count the frequency of each elements. but something is wrong with the counter one.

```
var unique_array=new Array();
var counter_array=new Array();
var unique=true;
for (i=0;i<text_array.length;i++){

    if (unique_array.length==0){
    unique_array.push(text_array[0]);
    counter_array.push(1);

    }
    else if(unique_array.length>0&&unique_array.length<=text_array.length){
        for (j=0; j<unique_array.length;j++){
            if (text_array[i]==unique_array[j]){
                counter_array[j]=counter_array[j]+1;// something wrong with the 
                alert(counter_array[j]);
                var unique=false;
            } 
        }
        if (unique==true){
            unique_array.push(text_array[i]);
            counter_array.push[1];
        }
        unique=true;
    }
```

Comment: Try using a site like [**jshint**](http://www.jshint.com) if you're having trouble with your code. It points out a few problems, including a syntax error with your closing brace.

Comment: `unique_array.length>0` is redundant in the *else* branch since you won't get there unless `length != 0`, and it can't be negative, so at that point it must be `> 0`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also simplify the code down using a hashmap and some ES5 higher-order functions:

```js
var text_array = ["a1","a1","a2","a3","a2","a4","a1","a5"];
var counts = {};
text_array.forEach(function(el) { 
    counts[el] = counts.hasOwnProperty(el) ? counts[el]+1 : 1;
});
var unique_array = Object.keys(counts);
var counter_array=unique_array.map(function(key) { return counts[key]; })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much more simply using an object. Let the values be the keys of an object, then just increment the count of each property as you go. At the end, you can get an array of the unique keys and their values:

```
var text_array = ['foo','bar','foo','fum','fum','foo'];
var i = text_array.length;
var obj = {};

while (i--) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(text_array[i])) {
    obj[text_array[i]]++;
  } else {
    obj[text_array[i]] = 1;
  }
}

console.log('Unique values: ' + Object.keys(obj));   // Unique values: foo,fum,bar
console.log('Value counts:  ' + Object.keys(obj).map(function(v){return obj[v]})); // Value counts:  3,2,1
```

Note that the sorting of counts in the output is purely coincidental.

As Jasvir posted, you can make it pretty concise:

```
var obj = {};
text_array.forEach(function(v) {
  obj.hasOwnProperty(v)? ++obj[v] : obj[v] = 1;
});
```

But the first example is a bit easier to digest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach is what's making it difficult. A hash table / associative array would be much easier to work with.

With a hash table (an object `{}` in JS), you can store each word in a key and increment the value of the key when you encounter the word again. Then, at the end, just go through the hash table and gather up all the keys which have small values. Those are your unique words.

```js
function get_unique_words(text_array) {

    var hash_table, i, unique_words, keys;

    hash_table = {};
    for(i = 0; i < text_array.length; i++) {
        if(hash_table[text_array[i]] === undefined) {
            hash_table[text_array[i]] = 1;
        } else {
            hash_table[text_array[i]]++;
        }
    }

    // go through the hash table and get all the unique words 
    unique_words = [];
    keys = Object.keys(hash_table);
    for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if(hash_table[keys[i]] === 1) {
            unique_words.push(keys[i]);
        }
    }

    return unique_words.sort();

}

console.log(get_unique_words(
    ['blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'goose', 'duck', 
    'mountain', 'rock', 'paper', 'rock', 'scissors']
));
```

Some issues and suggestions :

- Don't use `var` twice for the same variable.

  - Browsers deal with it ok, but for clarity you should only be declaring your variables once.
- Always localize your loop counters - forgetting a `var` before your `i` and `j` will cause them to become global variables.

  - This is relevant when you have a page with lots of code - all global variables will show up in the debugger's watch list at all times, making it harder to debug your code.)
- Use the array literal notation `[]` instead of the function form `Array`.

  - The function form is longer and it's easier to forget the `new`. It's also easier to read (IMO).
- Use more whitespace (it won't bite), such as before and after an equals sign:

  ```
  var x = 1; 
  // vs.
  var x=1;
  ```

  It makes the code easier to read and most people don't overdo it.
- Indent your code when it's inside a block (e.g. `function`, `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, etc.).

  - This makes it easier to read the control flow of the code and will help prevent bugs.
- Use three equals signs (`===`) unless you are using loose equality on purpose.

  - This will help someone looking at your code later (probably yourself) understand better what the test is supposed to be testing.